# Android ListView not able to change image based on condition

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to change the image associated withe ach item based on comndition which is not working.Items are not getting repeated but images are getting repeated

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_shopping_items,
                    null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txt = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
            holder.imgFavHis=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgFavHis);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        if(LocalDb.isLoggedIn()){           

            holder.txt.setText( arr.get(position)); 
            if(hisList.contains(arr.get(position))){
                holder.imgFavHis.setImageResource(R.drawable.icnhistory);
            }
            else if (favList.contains(arr.get(position)) ){
                holder.imgFavHis.setImageResource(R.drawable.icnfavorite);
            }

        }
        else{
                    holder.txt.setText(arr.get(position));
        }


        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Images get repeated if condition (LocalDb.isLoggedIn()) is false. convertView comes in getView() already with image. So, this image stays in this case. You can set null to imgFavHis in else-statement.

BTW, use the following

```
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return arr[position];
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Comment: return arr[position]; what does this return

Comment: ListView needs to know about your items. By returning arr[position] you show how items are linked to rows (item[0] - 1st row, item[1] - 2nd row and so on). Returning null is ok, but it may lead to bugs. For instance, if you change your items and not call notifyDataSetChanged() ListView will see this and let you know about your mistake by throwing an exception. So, it's totally up to you, but I suggest not to return null.

Comment: my arr is arraylist...but this requires an array

Comment: then use arr.get(position);